# How can I make $PATH stored in Vim match the actual environment variable $PATH?

Tags: environment-variables

It seems that when starting Vim, it stores the value of the environment variable `$PATH` into its own internal variable `$PATH`. Then, when using `$PATH` anywhere inside Vim, it gets expanded into the internal value instead of the actual value of the environment variable.

I think what I meant is best understood with an example.

1. In a shell, do `vim --clean`.
2. In Vim do `CTRL-Z` to suspend Vim.
3. `PATH=foo`
4. `fg`

Then, all the following commands will output the value of `$PATH` as it was before starting Vim, and *not* "foo".

```
:echo $PATH
:!echo $PATH
:echo expand('$PATH')
:echo getenv('PATH')
:echo environ()['PATH']
:echo system('echo $PATH')
```

Even doing `:terminal` then `echo $PATH` doesn't give "foo".

If I do `:!PATH=foo` then `:!echo $PATH`, I still do not get "foo".

I know I could do `:let $PATH = 'foo'` but that's not ideal when the value is more complicated.

Comment: Every process has a copy of environment of its own. This is a basic thing.

Comment: The process environment variable are copied from the parent to the child when the child process is created. By default child processes don't inherit the environment variable changes made after their creation (on some OS it is possible to change that but it is a design decision that has not been taken by VIM).

Comment: I figured you could maybe copy it from the parent, but `/proc/../environ` and `ps e` both return only the *initial* environment, and not the current one. No sure if there's a way to get the current environment. You could write some `/tmp/.env.$$` in your shell and read that with Vim, I suppose.